# Объект откатывается до предыдущего состояния в рекурсивном методе

Tags: c#, объекты, рекурсия

```
private void SetBestPath(State state, Point start, List<Point> targets,
        PathWithScore bestPath, PathWithScore current,
        Dictionary<Point, Dictionary<Point, PathWithCost>> edges)
    {
        if (bestPath.Score == state.Chests.Count) return;
        if (bestPath.Score < current.Score)
            bestPath = current;
        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            var pathWithCost = edges[start][target];
            var cost = pathWithCost.Cost + current.Cost;
            if (cost > state.Energy) continue;
            var joinedPath = current.Path.Concat(pathWithCost.Path.Skip(1)).ToList();
            var pathWithScore = new PathWithScore(joinedPath, cost, current.Score + 1);
            var updatedTargets = targets.ToList();
            updatedTargets.Remove(pathWithCost.End);
            SetBestPath(state, pathWithCost.End, updatedTargets, bestPath, pathWithScore, edges);
        }
    }
```

В методе при каждом вызове проверяется, что вычисленный путь проходит через большее количество вершин, чем предыдущий, и, если это так, то присваивает bestPath значение current. Но, когда заканчивается одна "ветка" рекурсии, значение bestPath откатывается к тому, которое было на предыдущих вызовах метода.
Казалось бы, значение bestPath должно сохраняться, так как это ссылочный тип, но на деле происходит то, что происходит.

Comment: *"Казалось бы, значение bestPath должно сохраняться, так как это ссылочный тип"* - нет, не должно

Comment: Вам нужна ссылка на bestPath

Comment: я ее постоянно передаю как аргумент

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 private void SetBestPath(State state, Point start, List<Point> targets,
    ref PathWithScore bestPath, PathWithScore current, ...) {
    ^^^
    ...
    SetBestPath(state, pathWithCost.End, updatedTargets, ref bestPath, ...);
 }                                                       ^^^
```

`ref` говорит о том, что значение ссылки внутри метода может измениться, и ссылка станет ссылаться на другой объект.

Comment: Почему нужен модификатор ref, ведь PathWithScore - класс, и в аргументы и так передается ссылка на объект?

Comment: @stn `ref` говорит о том, что значение ссылки внутри метода может измениться, и ссылка станет ссылаться на другой объект

Comment: @stn А вы [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) читали? Видели фразу "Не путайте понятие передачи по ссылке с понятием ссылочных типов."? Там есть и хороший пример и отсылка к [другой статье по теме](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters). Изучите.